# ACTION_UP event is working on emulator but not working on device

Tags: android

My app consist of LinearLayout  which include table row in it.after click on any row in given table i have shown the respective info which is working on emulator fine but when i deployed the same app on device it's not working as it should work on emulator.

ACTION_UP event is called in ontouchlistener.

Comment: Could you accept some answers to your questions, please? Also, provide some code, please.

Answer (score 3):

touching empty space in LinearLayout does not give an ACTION_UP or ACTION_MOVE.

It does however give an ACTION_DOWN